# Eclipse LibGDX folder sharing

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

(4/15/2014 Still no working answer to the question)

I used gdx-setup-ui.jar to create my Android/Desktop/HTML5 program which I imported into Eclipse.

```
myprogram
myprogram-android
myprogram-desktop
myprogram-html
```

My program runs fine on desktop and android, but when I run it as html I get an error if all of my classes are not in the same myprogram>src folder, if I put it in a sub folder in src then the html5 does not seem to access the class. If I take my classes out of the folder and put them in the root of myprogram>src they work. How can I fix this?

I also notice that when I do a symbolic link to the asset folder manually(without gdx-setup-ui.jar) my Java application will not find the pictures etc unless I physically copy the asset folder twice. I made sure the folder path was exactly the same and it still wouldn't detect it unless I made a second copy of the pictures. Strangely the gdx-setup-ui.jar does this symbolic copy and yet it works for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial explains how to [do it in Eclipse](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1537). And for completeness sake, here is how to [do it using ant and IntelliJ](http://www.crisi.ch/sharing-libgdx-assets-folder-between-android-and-desktop-project-in-intellij-idea/). I hope this was useful. I will try the Eclipse one now...

Comment: I already tried this and strangely it did not work, I tried both linking options, then I just tried physically copying it and it worked... it works when the setup-ui automatically creates the link... I will try again later... also the class names are not linked this way between the HTML and Core folder, how does the HTML know to look in the src folder of the Core folder plus the HTML folder... because it will not register classes in sub folders but the Android one will... It is quite confusing I will try this all again later and tell you if I have any progress.

Comment: I noticed the exact same things in the same order. What worked for me in the end was relying on the original links, making sure that the original dir residesin the android project, since that seems to be the most sensitive.

Comment: Hopefully someone will explain why this is. The only thing I can think of is there is some sort of configuration file that eclipse is importing from the folder that we have not looked at yet?